# R selenium method for downloading data for different year

Tags: r, tidyverse, rselenium, webautomation

The following code was written in one of my previous questions on same platform. I have to download data for 2020 however the URL doesn't change once 2020 is clicked on right hand column on given weblink. The code is opening 2020 page on Firefox however is not downloading required files (2020 files) in the system. It is downloading the 2021 files which I don't need. I am unable to figure out the issue.
The URL I am working on is : https://www.rbi.org.in/scripts/AnnualPublications.aspx?head=Handbook%20of%20Statistics%20on%20Indian%20Economy
The code is:

```
 library(tidyverse)
      library(stringr)
      library(purrr)
      library(rvest)
      library(RSelenium)
      
      rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4567L, verbose=F)
      remDr <- rD[["client"]]
      
      remDr$navigate("https://www.rbi.org.in/scripts/AnnualPublications.aspx?head=Handbook+of+Statistics+on+Indian+Economy")
elem<- remDr$findElement(using = "link text", "2020")
      elem$clickElement()
      page <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
      read_html(page) -> html
      html %>%
        html_nodes("a") %>%  
        html_attr("href") %>% 
        str_subset("\\.PDF") -> urls
      urls %>% str_split(.,'/') %>% unlist() %>% str_subset("\\.PDF") -> filenames
    
      for(u in 1:length(urls)) 
      {
        cat(paste('downloading: ', u, ' of ', length(urls)))
        download.file(urls[u], filenames[u], mode='wb')
      }
      system("taskkill /im java.exe /f", intern=FALSE, ignore.stdout=FALSE)
```

Comment: Your code worked fine for me. Was able to download the files in chrome.

Comment: Just to confirm u were able to download files of year 2020? Because in mine it is showing downloading but then system times out and nothing gets downloaded

Comment: Yeah I was able to download the 2020 files. Opened the pdf's and cross checked.

Comment: But then why it is not happening in mine system? I am unable to figure out? You have any idea or so? Happening because of version of R or something else? Just to confirm did you ran exact same code?

Comment: Yeah ran the same code. What error are you encountering?

Comment: Yes now working. Saved files in different location. However I am still facing same issue. The files are getting downloaded for 2021 year only not 2020. You can check that by seeing file size when files are getting downloaded. This is the main issue I am still facing

Comment: Maybe try using `xpath`  `remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", '//*[@id="2020"]')`

Comment: Nope. Same issue still

Comment: Try using `sys.sleep(5)` after loading webpage and clicking the element.

Comment: Nope. Still the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check whether you are on right page or not by obtaining the name of Handbook,

You are now on year 2021

```
remDr$navigate("https://www.rbi.org.in/scripts/AnnualPublications.aspx?head=Handbook+of+Statistics+on+Indian+Economy")
remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html() %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="accordion"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/text()[1]') %>% html_text()
[1] "Handbook of Statistics on the Indian Economy, 2020-21 "
```

Now you are year 2020

```
elem<- remDr$findElement(using = "link text", "2020")
elem$clickElement()
remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html() %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="accordion"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/text()[1]') %>% html_text()
  [1] "Handbook of Statistics on Indian Economy 2019-20 "
```

## **Edit:-**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)
```

Launch Browser

```
rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4567L, verbose=F)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
```

Load the webpage

```
remDr$navigate("https://www.rbi.org.in/scripts/AnnualPublications.aspx?head=Handbook+of+Statistics+on+Indian+Economy")
```

Click the year **2020**. Make sure you are getting the data for the right year.

```
remDr$findElement(using = "link text", "2020")$clickElement()
remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html() %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="accordion"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/text()[1]') %>% html_text()

[1] "Handbook of Statistics on the Indian Economy, 2020-21 "
```

Get the pdf name, url and start downloading

```
urls =  remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes("a") %>%  
  html_attr("href") %>% 
  str_subset("\\.PDF")

filenames = urls %>% str_split(.,'/') %>% unlist() %>% str_subset("\\.PDF")

for(u in 1:length(urls)){
  cat(paste('downloading: ', u, ' of ', length(urls)))
  download.file(urls[u], filenames[u], mode='wb')
}
```

Comment: Hi. The code is still recognizing URL for 2021 only and so files for 2021 are getting downloaded instead of 2020. Also if we check for 2020 handbook name then if I have to give multiple years as input then I will have to change each time ?

Comment: I am not able to get you. You need to click on each year to get the pdf's of respective years.

Comment: Yes. Basically I want that if I give 2019 or 2020 as my input in code then the files of that respective year gets downloaded.

Comment: Yeah, whatever is your input code for that respective year the files will get downloaded. If you want multiple year files then  you can use the loop.

Comment: Yes thank you. However the code which you have helped me with (the 2020 one) it is still downloading 2021 files. I am still stuck at same problem. Can you tell me where exactly should I add these particular 4 lines of 2020 code. Maybe I added at wrong place that is why code is still downloading for 2021